# How to fix unreachable code dedected warning

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, dblinq

dbLinq XMlMappingSource.cs contains code:

```
    public void ReadEmptyContent(XmlReader r, string name)
    {
        if (r.IsEmptyElement)
            r.ReadStartElement(name, DbmlNamespace);
        else
        {
            r.ReadStartElement(name, DbmlNamespace);
            for (r.MoveToContent(); r.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement; r.MoveToContent())
            {
                if (r.NamespaceURI != DbmlNamespace)
                    r.Skip();
                throw UnexpectedItemError(r);
            }
            r.ReadEndElement();
        }
    }
```

This causes compile warning

Warning CS0162  Unreachable code detected

at line

```
            for (r.MoveToContent(); r.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement; r.MoveToContent())
```

( https://github.com/DbLinq/dblinq2007/blob/d7a05bb452b98fd24bca5693da01ecfecd4f3d40/src/DbLinq/Data/Linq/Mapping/XmlMappingSource.cs#L176 )

in third part of for clause `r.MoveToContent()`
It looks like normal node traversal code and third part of for is reached.

How to fix this ?
Using .NET 4

Comment: `r.ReadEndElement();` is unreachable because you throwing straight forward exception as `throw UnexpectedItemError(r);`

Comment: You have  two if statements without curly braces. Those should always be a red flag to you, as it's a common mistake to misuse them. I suggest always using curly braces, even for single statements in the code block.

Comment: By the way, you can ignore if else statement, as you always execute `r.ReadStartElement(name, DbmlNamespace);`

Comment: @Love They could inverse the `if` and pull the `r.ReadStartElement(name, DbmlNamespace);` out and not need an `else`, if that's what you mean.

Comment: @juharr, yes. I meant that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Rawling stated you are throwing the exception no matter what.

Try changing the loop to this:

```
for (r.MoveToContent(); r.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement; r.MoveToContent())
            {
                if (r.NamespaceURI != DbmlNamespace)
                    r.Skip();
                else
                    throw UnexpectedItemError(r);
            }
```

This will fix your issue.

Answer (score 2):

You never execute the increment step, because your first run through the loop always throws an exception.